# Finding the corresponding Perron eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the Perron root and the corresponding Perron eigenvector of A.

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 &1 &1 \\ 1&0&1 \\ 1&1&0 \end{bmatrix}$

I figured out the Perron root which happens to be $ \lambda = 2 $. And I tried to figure out the eigenvector and got $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, but that turned out to be incorrect.

Can someone show me how to find the Perron eigenvector for the Perron root 2?

[image: The wrong eigenvector]

Comment: Why do you claim it is incorrect?

Comment: I edited the original post showing I got it incorrect.

Comment: Perhaps in your class the Perron eigenvector is defined as a vector with the usual properties, plus it must have $1$-norm equal to $1$. Try $\frac 1 3\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$.

Comment: Yes, this was indeed correct, thank you. I'm not sure why we have to normalize it, because I don't see that in the textbook anywhere. But i'll try to find out.

Comment: Actually, I checked it, and having $1$-norm equal to $1$ is the standard definition of the Perron eigenvector. I didn't recall this at the time of my first comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to normalize your vector.  The answer should indeed be
$$
\pmatrix{1/3\\1/3\\1/3}
$$